# How to conserve digital proof?

Tags: contract-law, internet, civil-law

There is some statement, put in digital form on the internet, wich I would like to conserve. The issue is its not available freely but rather after a login,so Internet Archive isn't an Option.

How do I conserve this statement and its source in a way that its authenticity can be proven?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take screenshots, film a video of you taking the screenshots and saying what you are doing and when. For utmost reliability have witnesses standing by.

Comment: For even further reliability, have at least one of the witnesses be a notary.  Have all of the witnesses sign the screenshot and have the notary notarize it.